# node.js emailing from contact me section

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I just created a static portfolio bootstrap website as a practice and there is a contact me section at the bottom of the site where you can type in your name, phone number, email and some text. This website was created originally as a static one but after me watched a couple of youtube videos on how to sending email by using node.js and I tested it out in a separate project and the code worked. So I decided to add this functionality to this static website and I did, but the code I learned is no longer working. I am very new to node.js and now I think the whole idea could be wrong in the first place as I might need to have different folder structure / or environment set up at least to get this work at the very beginning and not just simply adding something on top of it, is that correct.
I have provided an image of my folder structure and my app.js file. The app.js has been placed in the public folder directory (as I found out after some research) and also added a link to html file    for the html page to access to the JavaScript file. However, once I placed app.js inside the public folder, I kept getting errors when I run node.js app.js. It seems it not working anymore.
Furthermore, the code you have seen below is from a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/nF9g1825mwk) I followed where the contact form was the only thing it renders, however, in my case, the contact form is part of the html file and how do I render the form if the contact form is a part of a html file. Can anyone help me?

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'jasonking4ever@gmail.com', // generated ethereal user
            pass: 'senyang123'  // generated ethereal password
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Contact Form" <jasonking4ever@gmail.com>', // sender address
        to: 'syan19@live.cn', // list of receivers
        subject: 'You have a new contact request', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: output // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        res.render('contact', { msg: 'Email has been sent' });
    });
})

app.listen('3000', () => console.log('the server is starting...'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey there your server file which i can see is app.js must me in the root directory(by root i mean in your folder root directory) not in public folder, the public folder is meant to serve public file(let say UI related file.). So remove your app.js from there and put in your folder root directory and run node.I hope that helps.

Comment: @Sen123 you may want to read up on [ExpressJS's documentation on serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).